# Submitted value seems to be ignored

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu which is suposed to be processed when its value is changed.
The xhtml is quite generic so it's not very clear. Here it is:

```
<p:selectOneMenu 
    id="#{myId}"
    value="#{obj[attr]}"
    panelStyle="font-size: 10px;"
    disabled="#{cc.attrs.grid.readonly}"
    style="margin-top: 3px; width:79px;" 
    styleClass="#{change.getChangeClass(cc.attrs.grid)} toUpdate">
    <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.grid.valuesString}" var="elem" itemValue="#{elem}" itemLabel="#{elem}"/>
    <f:validator validatorId="GenericValidator" />
    <p:ajax 
      process="@this" 
      listener="#{rules.process()}" 
      update="@this"/>
```

Here is a part of the generated html which is clearer:

```
    behaviors:{change:function(event){
      PrimeFaces.ab({
        source:'masterCenter:fuel3Content:j_idt621:fuel_codeCat',
        event:'valueChange',
        process:'masterCenter:fuel3Content:j_idt621:fuel_codeCat',
        update:'masterCenter:fuel3Content:j_idt621:fuel_codeCat'}, arguments[1]);}
    }
```

When I select a value, it gets posted (I can see with chrome tools that it is in the form data being posted). 
But my validation method (GenericValidator.validate()) is not called.
When I submit the whole form, the validation method is called, but it indicates that the value of the combo is null.
I have the feeling that this value is not set as it should during the apply request values phase.

But this behaviour depends on the context:
This selectOneMenu is in a panel. The first time I open this panel (loaded with ajax), it works fine. I can change the value of the selectOneMenu and my validation method is called with the value that I've chosen.
Now when I open this panel again, the selectOneMenu doesn't work any more. However the generated html is exactly the same.
I also have the same behaviour with a p:inputTextarea in this form.

I'm using primefaces 3.4.1 with Mojarra 2.1.10. It looks to me like a primefaces/mojarra bug, but I haven't found notes of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

in value expression `value="#{obj[attr]}"`, why you are using a map? And how you set attr value? can you give more details?

Comment: It's not a map. The string between the square brackets is a string whose value is the name of the property to get.

Answer (score 0):

In versions prior to jsf 2.0 validaton is ignored for empty and null fields. In jsf 2.0 if your jsf runs in environment where bean validation is supported then your empty or null fields are validated by default.

If you are using non j2ee 6 compliant servers like tomcat 6 or jetty in which bean validation is not supported then validation won't happen for null or empty fields.

If you want to enforce validation on empty fields you can use either `required="true"` or

```
  <context-param>  
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>  
    <param-value>true</param-value>  
  </context-param>
```

Hope this helps. Leave a comment if you need further help

Comment: The problem is that I select a value in the combo. The value is not null nor empty. But during partial submit (ajax event when the combo is changed), the validation method is not called. Then when I submit the whole form, the validation method is called but the value is empty (even though in the request I can see that the value has been sent). So I suspect that the problem occurs during the apply request phase.